# Remove Gaps Between Bars in Plotly

Tags: r, bar-chart, r-plotly

I am trying to create a Marimekko chart in R using Plotly. Essentially, this is just a stacked, variable-width bar chart with both bars directly adjacent to one another. Currently, my attempt looks like this:

[image]

The code to create it is here:

```
bar.test <- plot_ly(type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(title = paste0("Newark Charter vs District BTO Makeup"),
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = "Percent BTO", tickformat = "%")) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~test1$sch.type, y = ~test1$y, width = ~test1$width, 
            marker = list(color = c(blue.dark.opq, red.opq.2, blue.dark.opq, red.opq.2) ,
                            line = list(color = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)' , width = 2))) %>% 
  add_annotations(x = ~test1$sch.type, y = ~test1$annotation.y,
                  text = paste0("<b>", 100*round(test1$y, 3), "%"),
                  showarrow = F,
                  font = list(size = 14, color = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)')) %>% 
  add_annotations(x = ~test1$sch.type, y = ~test1$all.y,
                  text = paste0(test1$all.count), showarrow = F,
                  font = list(size = 14, color = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)')) %>% 
  hide_legend()
```

And the data looks like this:

[image]

My goal is simply to have there be no gap between the bars. I have tried to do this with the `bargap` argument but have read that assigning the bars a width makes Plotly ignore the `bargap` argument. I've also read a potential workaround is to manually change the bars' `offset` argument. However, I have many of these figures with varying widths and percents so any solution can't be manual.

Comment: You don't need to use `~` when you are supplying the name of the data anyway. Either use `~` or `test1$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by having custom `x` and using `bargap = 0` in layout

```r
library(plotly)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout

test1 <- data.frame(
    city.state = "Newark",
    sch.type = c("Charter", "Charter", "District", "District"),
    bto.stat = c(0,1,0,1),
    y = c(.7, .3, .1, .9),
    width = c(.3, .3, .7, .7),
    x = c(.15, .15, .65, .65),
    annotation.y = c(.3, .8, .05, .55),
    all.count = c(46000, 46000, 99000, 99000),
    all.y = c(1,1,1,1)
    )

bar.test <- plot_ly(type = "bar") %>%
    add_trace(x = test1$x,
              y = test1$y,
              width = test1$width,
              marker = list(
                color = c("blue", "red", "blue", "red") ,
                line = list(color = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)' , width = 2)
                )
              ) %>%
    layout(bargap = 0)

bar.test
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This solution works because of the custom X values. Setting bargap = 0 doesn't actually do anything. Plotly ignores bargap when bar width is assigned. I think this is a good solution to my problem because X values can be calculated systematically, so there's no manual input needed. The then add the correct labels via annotation, how would I first remove the 0.15 and 0.65 from showing?

Comment: You can use `tickmode = "array"` to customise the axis ticks.  https://plot.ly/r/tick-formatting/

Comment: related plotly.js issue: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/930

Answer (score 2):

A Marimekko chart is more commonly known as a "Mosaic Plot". You can make one in `ggplot` using `ggmosaic`, and then convert it to plotly using `ggplotly`.  You did not provide copyable data in the question, so here is an example using the mtcars dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggmosaic)
library(plotly)

p <- mtcars %>%
       lapply(as.factor) %>%
       as.data.frame() %>%
       count(cyl, gear)  %>%
       ggplot() +
         geom_mosaic(aes(weight = n, x = product(cyl), fill = gear)) +
         labs(x = 'Cylinders', y = 'Gears')
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]