# Ignore the missing level of color variable in bar plot in Plotly R

Tags: r, plotly

I want to ignore the missing level of color variable to avoid the gap between bars in plotly.

This is data set

```
dt <- data.frame(x = c("apple", "apple","apple","banana", "banana", "banana"),
                 y = c("green", "red","blue", "green","green","yellow"),
                 n = c(23, 45, 23, 11, 43, 27))
plotly::plot_ly(dt, x = dt$x, y = dt$n, color = dt$y)

       x      y  n
1  apple  green 23
2  apple    red 45
3  apple   blue 23
4 banana  green 11
5 banana  green 43
6 banana yellow 27
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Gaps Between Bars in Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924514/remove-gaps-between-bars-in-plotly)

Comment: It's not, the gap between groups. you can see there are 4 levels of color, but banana group had only 2 levels, it create a gap between levels.There is no problem if I use ggplot2

Comment: This is an [open issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/930) in the underlying JS library. Accordingly the only solution I currently see is following the `layout(bargap = 0)` approach I linked above.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the solution is nice, but it's complicated for my shiny app, due to unknown variables from the users data.